# Playing 1st track while recording to a 2nd track (overdubbing)

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, music, microphone, audacity

I'm trying to play a 20 min flac file on the first track while recording the mic to a second track.

When I try and record while overdub is checked in Audacity the other tracks play fine and another track records but after about 6-8 mins it stops recording and it stops playing.

I'm using Audacity Audacity 2.1.1-alpha-Apr 8 2015 Ubuntu 14.04 16 gig RAM 200 gig SSD (80 gig free plenty of space available) .

This also happen with the stable version of Audacity in the Ubuntu repos

Any idea of a workaround or another program that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Found a [workaround](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Release_Notes_2.1.0#Miscellaneous_platform-specific_issues)

> #### Miscellaneous platform-specific issues
>
> (Linux) A playback or recording freeze, recording dropouts or fast playback may occur when using PulseAudio. Freezes may be caused by repeatedly starting and stopping playback or recording in quick succession (or by holding down the Play or Record button). Workarounds: Try launching Audacity from the terminal with the pulse latency set to 30 ms in an environment variable:
>
> ```
> env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 audacity
> ```
>
> If you get underruns noted in the terminal, try a higher number in the `PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC` command. If the problem is unchanged, try a lower number. Alternatively, bypass pulseaudio by setting the playback and recording device to an ALSA (hw) choice in Device Toolbar.

See [this topic](http://audacityteam.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=5064) on the Audacity forum.